# Sequential Information Projection (Repeated information property)

Tags: information-theory

The lecture note [Here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-441-information-theory-spring-2016/lecture-notes/MIT6_441S16_chapter_12.pdf) at last paragraph of page 136 explained the concept of 'repeated information projection' without much proof. I am wondering how can I prove the following property. Any help would be appreciated

**Repeated information projection**

If $Q_1$ is the information projection of $P$ onto $\Lambda_1$ (that is,

$$
D\left(Q_1 \parallel P \right) = \inf_{Q \in \Lambda_1}D\left(Q \parallel P\right).
$$

Also, the $Q_2$ is the information projection of $Q_1$ onto $\Lambda_1 \cap \Lambda_2$ (that is, 
$$
D\left(Q_2 \parallel Q_1 \right) = \inf_{R \in \Lambda_1 \cap \Lambda_2}D\left(R \parallel Q_1\right).
$$

Then $D\left(Q_2 \parallel P \right) = \inf_{S \in \Lambda_1 \cap \Lambda_2} D\left(S \parallel P \right)$, too.

Comment: This follows from thm 12.2 in the notes: For every $S \in \Lambda_1 \cap \Lambda_2 \subset \Lambda_1, D(S\|P) \ge D(S\|Q_1) + D(Q_1\|P),$ and thus the last optimisation problem and the middle one are equivalent given $Q_1.$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it is unclear to me that the last optimization and the middle one are equivalent. I understand putting $Q_2$ in the $D(Q_2 \parallel Q_1)$ achieves the minimum on the r.h.s.; however, is it necessarily the minimize the l.h.s too?

Comment: You're quite right, I've (badly) jumped the gun. Let me think a bit more.

Comment: Okay, this follows easily for linear families (of the form $\Lambda_{t,f} := \{Q: \mathbb{E}_Q[f(X)] \ge t\}$) since then the inequalty is an equality (I suspect this is what I had in mind earlier). Perhaps then the fact that convex sets are intersections of half-spaces can be invoked. I shall try to fill stuff in when I have the time.

Comment: @stochasticboy321, Thank you very much for your intuition. Could you please explain, how these become equality under half-space assumption?

Comment: Cross-posted on CSTheory and Math, and re-posted on CSTheory a second time: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2759685/14578, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/40698/5038, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/40716/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  Please do not re-post your question a second time to get more attention to it.  Once you have gained enough reputation, you can use a bounty to draw attention to your question.